# Javascript handling an array on model ember

Tags: javascript

Hey im having trouble handling an array. 
On console i write (ember)

```
this.get('model');
```

Which returns

```
[a, a, a]
```

Each "a" itself contains of

```
fname: "fsafasPerson1"
gender: a
id: 1
lname: "fasFirst"
```

What i would like is to get each "a's" fname for starters.

```
    fname : "This is the first name"
    fname : " 2nd"
    fname : "third"
```

---

Working example

```
var fnames = [];
var array = this.get('model')
$.each(array, function(array, obj) {
    fnames.push(obj.fname);
});
console.log(fnames);
```

Cheers

Kristjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do,

```
var fnames = [];

$.each(obj, function(i, obj) {
    fnames.push(obj.fname);
});
console.log(fnames); // array of fname
```